# Testing redux-saga catch error handling with jest

Tags: testing, redux, jestjs, anonymous-function, redux-saga

I'm trying to test that my error-handling action is called when my saga throws an error.

Here's my saga code:

```
function* createMenu({ values }) {
    try {
        do some stuff...
    } catch (err) {
        yield put(displayApiError(err));
    }
}
```

And here's my test code:

```
const saga = createMenu(mockAction);
const mockError = 'err';

it('calls displayApiError()', () => {
    saga.next();
    const result = saga.throw(mockError);

    expect(result.value).toEqual(put(displayApiError(mockError)));
});
```

And this is what I see in my jest output:

```
● createMenu › Failure › calls displayApiError()

expect(received).toEqual(expected)

Expected value to equal:
  {"@@redux-saga/IO": true, "PUT": {"action": [Function anonymous], "channel": null}}
Received:
  {"@@redux-saga/IO": true, "PUT": {"action": [Function anonymous], "channel": null}}

Difference:

Compared values have no visual difference.
```

I'm assuming it's the `Function anonymous` part that's the issue. I've tried executing both the compared functions themselves and they are both calling `displayApiError` in the same way.

So why is the test still failing?

Answer (score 0):

What are the contents of `displayApiError(mockError)`? Seems like your returning a thunk or anonymous function? Sagas `put` works with plain redux actions.

A couple of general thoughts on testing anonymous functions in redux sagas:

1. If you are just concerned with asserting the effect and not the function itself.

   ```
   const callEffect = call(() => {});  
   callEffect.CALL.fn = expect.any(Function);  
   expect(result.value).toEqual(callEffect);
   ```

Note passing `expect.any(Function)` to some saga effects like `call` may raise as they assert the type.

2. Inspect the value's contents instead of using toEqual directly on the effect.

   ```
   const fn = result.value.CALL.fn;  
   const result = fn();  
   // then assert something about result
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your saga to use [`call` effect](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#callfn-args);

```
function* createMenu({ values }) {
    try {
        do some stuff...
    } catch (err) {
        const action = yield call(displayApiError, err)
        yield put(action);
    }
}
```

Now it is testable

```
const saga = createMenu(mockAction);
const mockError = 'err';
const mockActiom = {};

it('calls displayApiError()', () => {
    saga.next();
    let result  = saga.throw(mockError);

    // now you are actually testing that displayApiError been called
    // not that the event was dispatched
    expect(result.value).toEqual(call(displayApiError, mockError));

    // test for dispatch if necessary
    result = saga.next(mockAction);
    expect(result.value).toEqual(put(mockAction));
});
```